# create react app npm run start don't find a module

Tags: javascript, create-react-app, npm-start

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Project\node_modules\raw-body\node_modules\iconv-lite\lib\index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
    at tryPackage (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:353:19)
    at Function.Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:566:18)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:919:27)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Project\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:18:13)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\Project\\node_modules\\raw-body\\node_modules\\iconv-lite\\package.json',
  requestPath: 'iconv-lite'
}
```

- I try delete  package.json and run npm install
- I try delete node_module and run npm install

both tries doesn't word.

Comment: You should never delete package.json because npm will recognize the packages from it and install them. You can only delete package-lock.json. The reason why it throws this error is because you don't have package.json.

Comment: Yes, I suspect you will need to run `npm install` to generate a lock file. You should never delete your package.json. Try restoring it if you're using git and then run npm install.